# Memory leak in QSerialBus work

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

**Hello everyone!**

I've got problem with my ModBus realisation via `QSerialBus` library on **Qt 5.8**.

**The problem is** - when I try to read a list of discrete inputs on a high speed, the program catch a memory leak - about *300-350Kb* per second.

So, here the code of function that causes leak:

```
void ModBus::queue()
{
    if(!_readList.isEmpty())
    {
        if(!checkState())
        {
            _readList.clear();
            _curPos = DiscInputPos::Full;
            queue();
            return;
        }

        QModbusDataUnit readData = QModbusDataUnit(QModbusDataUnit::DiscreteInputs, _readList.first(), 1);
        if(auto *reply = _client->sendReadRequest(readData, _serverNum))
        {
            if(!reply->isFinished())
            {
                connect(reply, &QModbusReply::errorOccurred, [=] (QModbusDevice::Error e)
                {
                    reply->deleteLater();
                    if(e == QModbusDevice::TimeoutError)
                    {
                        _readList.clear();
                        _curPos = DiscInputPos::Full;
                        stop();
                        start();
                        queue();
                    }
                });
                connect(reply, &QModbusReply::finished, this, [=]
                {
                    if(reply->error() == QModbusDevice::NoError)
                    {
                        if(reply->result().valueCount() > 0)
                        {
                            _curPos = (DiscInputPos) reply->result().value(0);
                            if(_curPos == DiscInputPos::Clear)
                                _readList.removeFirst();
                            else
                                _readList.clear();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _readList.clear();
                        _curPos = DiscInputPos::Full;
                    }

                    reply->deleteLater();
                    queue();
                });
            }
            else
                delete reply;
        }
        else
        {
            delete reply;
            _readList.clear();
            _curPos = DiscInputPos::Full;
            queue();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        emit sendReadResult(_curPos);
        _curPos = DiscInputPos::Full;
    }
}
```

`_client` — `QModbusTcpClient`

`bool checkState()` — does nothing special unless checking Connected state.

Maximum `_readList` size is **4**.

If I comment a part of code with `_client->sendReadRequest` - everything goes alright without any leak. Can anybody explain - what it can be?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Maybe QApplication's event dispatcher have not much time to delete objects (replies) marked as "deleteLater"? What happens with memory if stop high speed inputs?

Comment: I see several "delete reply", but the normal path don't have it.

Comment: @AdrianMaire, yes. I did as an [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialbus-modbus-master-example.html). Even though I use `delete` instead of `deleteLater()` - nothing changes.

Comment: @em2er, memory doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Can you count the reply's copies and corresponding count of lambda call's slots? Maybe some of replies have not emit `errorOccurred` and `finished` signals?

Comment: @em2er, after `QPair(1232,1232)` I lost my interest. Leaks still here...

Comment: @em2er Time doesn't factor in it at all. If you return control to the event loop, you're **guaranteed** that all deletions will be processed before the loop cedes control to the next event handler. The question of time makes no sense where each event loop is constrained to a single thread: only one thing can happen at a time, and the passage of time is not measured and doesn't affect behavior as far as those deletions go.

Comment: @KubaOber, well, in fact `ModBus` class works in other thread. Its emits signals through DirectConnection to main thread. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem via timer on **0.5 sec** (less causes leaks too), that ticks as single shot from class that check the answer from `ModBus` class. There is still leaks, but much-much less. If **1 sec** - there is no leaks.

```
connect(d, &ModBus::sendReadResult, this, &StatusesWorker::getRead);

void StatusesWorker::getRead(DiscInputPos s)
{
        bool cleared = (s == DiscInputPos::Clear);

        if(!cleared)
            emit badSensors();
        else
            emit clearSensors();

        QTimer::singleShot(500, [=] { checkSensor(id); });
    }
}
```

But I think this is bad solution.

**UPD.**

Qt Community [solved](https://forum.qt.io/topic/77227/qserialbus-memory-leak/4) the problem like that:

```
connect(reply, &QModbusReply::destroyed, [this] { QTimer::singleShot(60, [this] { queue(); }); });
```

And it's work faster without leaks. Of course, `checkSensor()` function now without timer.

Comment: This is not a solution. Run it under a memory profiler and see what exactly leaks. Use a debug Qt build. As it stands you still have a leak, and you still don't understand where it leaks, so you still can't be sure if this leak won't get worse when you change something else in the code.

Comment: @KubaOber, it's seems to be, like said man in Qt Community: "calling queue in a loop that doesn't let the event loop run properly". So, see **upd**, I guess this is better solution in this situation.